# jQuery - Show Error Message At Top Of Form

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I'm working on a form using the materialize framework. I've got my inputs set up to visually indicate an error when a user does not meet the requirements of a field (i.e. an invalid email address) by turning the input field line red. I am being tasked with also showing a prompt at the top of the form indicating the user should fix the errors before proceeding.

Using .blur() I'm able to get the prompt to slide down when the validation detects an error. However, when the focus changes back to the field with the error, the prompt goes away even though the input field shows the red line until the requirements are met. The prompt should stay until the class "invalid" is removed. I built a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wopwL8wL/5/) to demonstrate this.

I understand why the form is behaving this way. Is there something that would work better in this situation then .blur()?

```js
// Show Error Prompt At Top
$(function() {
  $("input").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":invalid")) {
      $(".e5").slideDown("slow");
    } else if ($(this).is(":valid")) {
      $(".e5").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.e5 {
  display: none;
  color: #F44336;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="e5"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please correct errors and re-submit</div>
  <div class="input-field suffix">
    <label class="sr-only" for="primary_phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input id="primary_phone" type="tel" pattern="^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$" maxlength="14" class="validate" />
    <label for="primary_phone">Phone Number</label>
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    <p id="primary_phone_err" class="errp" style="display:none;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field suffix">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email_address">Email </label>
    <input id="email_address" type="email" maxlength="45" onchange="clean(this);" class="validate" />
    <label for="email_address">Email</label>
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    <p id="email_address_err" class="error" style="display:none;"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a single error message container for all of the inputs:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":invalid")) {
      $(".e5").slideDown("slow");
    } else if ($(this).is(":valid")) {
      $(".e5").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
```

So when the user blurs an input that has no errors, you are clearing out the error message.

I suggest that rather than making the event handler responsible for showing or hiding the error message, you instead report to a central object whether or not the current input has an error. Multiple inputs could each individually register whether or not they have an error. (You'll probably want some sort of ID or key to keep track of which error message belongs to which input.)

The central object would then be responsible for showing or hiding the error message whenever an error is added or removed. You could allow multiple error messages, which would all be shown, or you could have one error message replace another. The important thing is that each input is only allowed to add an error or clear *it's own error* (not another input's error).

Or, you could initiate a scan each time an input is blurred, where your object will interrogate each input looking for an error. So rather than each input adding or removing the error, each input would initiate a form-wide scan that would examine and update all inputs.

How exactly to do that is entirely up to you, and there are many good strategies depending on your technology stack. Detailing exactly how to do that is going to be out of scope for an SO answer, in my opinion, but there's a really good [MDN article on form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) that may help you get started.